# nodejs WriteStream only writes a single line

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, streamwriter

I'm trying to have my program write the contents of an array filled with JSON packets to a text file specified at initialization, right before exit.  However, instead of writing the entire array the program insists on only writing a single packet to the file instead of the hundreds of packets it should be writing.  I have a for loop that iterates through the array and I call stream.write(messageArray[i]) on each element in the array.

The array is populated with JSON received by a datagram socket and it maintains a rolling window of the last 80 seconds of traffic.  This means that the array will always only hold the last 80 seconds of data in it. Here is some of the code. I omitted the time shift because i know it works.

```
var filename = String(process.argv[2]);
var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
var messageArray= [];

server.on('message', function(message, rinfo){
try{
    messageArray.push(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(message)));
}
catch(e)
   {console.log(e); console.log(message);}
total++;

});
server.on('listening', function(){
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('server listening on ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
});
server.bind(5139);

function exitHandler(options, err){
    if(err) console.log(err.stack);
    if(options.exit){

        stream.on('error', function(err){
            console.log(err.stack);
        });
        var i = 0;
        for(i; i< messageArray.length; i++)
                stream.write(messageArray[i] + ",\r\n");
        stream.end();
        process.exit();
    } 
}

process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit:true}));

process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler.bind(null , {exit:true}));
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The writes could be delayed and the exit handler is synchronous, so the process exits after the handler is called -- possibly causing writes to never happen.

What you should do instead is to write synchronously to the file:

```
var filename = String(process.argv[2]);
var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
var fs = require('fs');
var messageArray= [];

server.on('message', function(message, rinfo){
try{
    messageArray.push(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(message)));
}
catch(e)
   {console.log(e); console.log(message);}
total++;

});
server.on('listening', function(){
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('server listening on ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
});
server.bind(5139);

function exitHandler(options, err){
    if(err) console.log(err.stack);
    if(options.exit){
        fs.writeFileSync(filename, messageArray.join(',\r\n'));
        process.exit();
    } 
}

process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit:true}));

process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler.bind(null , {exit:true}));
```